# Using php inside javascript in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, date

I have got the following code in a javascript(jquery) file  called custom.js:

```
    blabla = new Date(2014, 06 - 1, 2);
        $('.days').countdown({
        until: blabla,
        layout: '{dn} {dl}',
```

1.Now i want  a user to be able to change the above date. I have created a theme options page called theme-options.php

2.I am  using `<?php require_once('theme-options.php'); ?>` in the functions.php to link to theme-options.php.

3.This is theme-options.php:

```
<?php
add_action('admin_menu', 'director_create_menu');
function director_create_menu() {
add_submenu_page( 'themes.php', ' Theme Options',
'Theme Options', 'administrator', __FILE__,
'director_settings_page');
add_action( 'admin_init', 'director_register_settings' );
}
function director_register_settings() {
register_setting( 'director-settings-group', 'director_date' );
}

div class="wrap">
  <h2>Theme Settings</h2>
  <form id="landingOptions" method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'director-settings-group' ); ?>
    <table class="form-table">
<tr valign="top">
          <th scope="row">Date:</th>
          <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="2014, 06 - 1, 2" name="director_date"
            value="<?php print get_option('director_date');
            ?>" />
          </td>
        </tr>
<p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Basically what is happening is that there is a theme options page.A user gives a date inside it. Now i want to use that date inside the javascript file.
If I had to use it inside index.php it would've been

```
<?php $date = get_option('director_date'); ?>
<?php if( $date ) : ?> <?php echo $date; ?><?php endif; ?>);
```

. However this is javascript. How do i implement such an action here?

An alternative path but still doesn't work.Rename custom.js to custom.php and add:

```
           gapinvite = new Date(<?php $date = get_option('director_date'); ?>
           <?php if( $date ) : ?> <?php echo $date; ?><?php endif; ?>);
           $('.days').countdown({
           until: gapinvite,
           layout: '{dn} {dl}',
```

And in functions.php:

```
<?php require_once('js/custom.php'); ?>
```

Comment: That does not work: javascript is interpreted on the _client_ side, it cannot access code on the _server_ side. You will have to make an additional request (AJAX or similar) or you need to create that javascript snippet in a dynamical manner (for example by use of php). I'd go for the second option. Create a php script that outputs the javascript just as required and post it with the right content header.

Comment: Could you please explain @arkascha how that could be done?

Comment: I did, didn't I? You create the javascript by a php script. That way the javascript does contain the value you require, since it has been generated. Since you have that value at php level you should be able to do so. I did that many times. You can create any type of file you want to by means of php, not just html markup.

Comment: Thanks arkascha. I did the same however i get an error. There is something wrong with the code. Have a look at the edited answer.

Comment: Sorry, no, I cannot spot where you generate dynamic javascript from php in your description. That `custom.js` is a static file if I get you right. You cannot have dynamic stuff in a static file, obviously.

Comment: Have a look at the edited question

Comment: Ah, sorry, now I spot it at the bottom of your question. Looks ok, why do you say it does not work? Are you sure that _that_ file is loaded in the browser and not the static version? Check with your browsers development console.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). Although ostensibly for translation, it lets you pass PHP values to JS. [Here's a fairly good walkthrough on how to use it](http://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/).

**EDIT:**

First, ensure that you are loading your JS using `wp_enqueue_script`, as you will need to refer to the *handle*. In your `functions.php` you'd have:

```
$date = get_option('director_date');
wp_enqueue_script('my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'js/my-script.js');
wp_localize_script('my-script', 'my_script_vars', array(
        'date' => $date
    )
);
```

`wp_localize_script` takes three arguments:

1. The *handle* of he script to pass the variables object to. This  should match the handle being used in `wp_enqueue_script`
2. The name of the variable object you want to create. You will use this name to refer to the object in JS
3. The array of variable to pass to the object. Here I'm just passing the `$date` variable we declared earlier, but you can obviously pass whatever you want.

Then in `my-script.js`, you'd access this object very simply:

```
var $date = my_scripts_vars.date;
alert($date); // Or do whatever you want with it
```

Comment: wp_localize_script is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

In `index.php`, you can do something like:

```
<?php $date = get_option('director_date'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">var generated_date = '<?php echo $date; ?>';</script>
```

Just make sure you do this before you include the JavaScript where you want to reference the `generated_date` variable you just created.

Comment: That won't work as soon as you have any security features active inside your browser. Most browsers will not execute inline javascript any more these days. And that makes sense.

Comment: What security features and what browsers? As far as I can tell, you are referring to the W3C [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/CSP/Introducing_Content_Security_Policy) proposal, but my research tells me that support for this is only included in the **very latest** browsers and that support is in response to a _specific header_ optionally sent by the web server. This is very, very different from 'Most browsers will not execute inline javascript [] these days'.

Comment: @arkascha - Please elaborate on what you mean by "Most browsers will not execute inline javascript any more these days. And that makes sense."

Comment: Whilst it is true that this limitation only refers to recent versions of browsers this does not make the statement untrue. Most users upgrade their software on a regular base these days (fortunately), so the majority of users _will_ use those recent versions. Also it is true that this behavior can be controlled via http headers. However this control is not trivial, I found that in many cases this leads to a general "allow all" policy which is not desirable. Inline scripts open a security thread and it is safest not to open that gap again. This is why I would advise against such solution.

Comment: I think the confusion is over what those browsers do by default. Sure, a user may hit my webpage with the most upgraded version of Firefox or Chrome, but unless I have specifically set up my website with respect to CSP, they're not just going to blatantly refuse to load any inline scripts.

Comment: Related question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359108/should-i-completely-stop-using-inline-javascript